# Maven conflicting dependency kafka-stream-test-utils and kafka-streams

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka

Getting this Esception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/streams/internals/QuietStreamsConfig.

Possibly because of dependency conflict. Related jars in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams-test-utils</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.0-ccs</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId> org.apache.kafka</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

When I run this command
**
 mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=org.apache.kafka
**

```
com.walmart.sims.ica:fault-handler:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams-test-utils:jar:5.5.0-ccs:test
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:jar:5.5.0-ccs:test - omitted for conflict with 1.0.1)
[INFO] |  \- (org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:5.5.0-ccs:test - omitted for conflict with 1.0.1)
[INFO] +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.kafka:connect-json:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.kafka:connect-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] \- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:1.0.1:compile
```

So my test dependencies are getting omitted due to conflict because of which I get ClassNotFoundException when I run my test.

How should I resolve the conflict such that dependencies from test-utils are available at test scope otherwise at compile scope kafka-streams and kafka-clients dependencies are used?

Answer (score 1):

What's the point of using one version in real prod code and much newer version of dependency for test code?
I would recommend to either downgrade `kafka-streams-test-utils` to a version that uses `kafka-streams:1.0.1` or upgrade `kafka-streams` version used by your app to 5.5.0-ccs. I do not think test-utils version 5.5.0-css will work correctly with stream version 1.0.1 anyway.
But if you want to try you can exclude kafka-streams and kafka-client dependencies from test-utils

Comment: Yes, you are right. I synced up both test and streams version and  made them 2.4.0. Although I had to rework due  to evolving contract. But it worked well.